# How to plot multiple graphs from file for each 3 columns ? in python

Tags: python

I don't see the strategy to work on it. I have a file, with several columns, each 3 columns represent a graph. The first column are the title and the two others column are x and y.

| "Body" | "x" | "y " | "Skin" | "x" | "y " | "Head" | "x" | "y " |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 0 | 100 |  | 0 | 100 |  | 0 | 100 |
|  | 1 | 99 |  | 0 | 99 |  | 0 | 98 |

I would like to have multiple graph. I thought that the solution would be to separate the table over 3 but it's not very smart.
I didn't find a function in panda or matplotlib. Do you have an idea?

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by "multiple grpah"?  do you want one graph for body, skin, head each? Which kind of graph do you want, e.g. a scatterplot?

Comment: Yes I want a graph with body, skin, head, and the kind of graph will be a line. Thank for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the columns like this:

```
for i in enumerate(df.columns):
    if i%3 == 2:
        _title = df.iloc[0,i-2]
        x = df.iloc[:,i-1]
        y = df.iloc[:,i]
        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import matplorlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,1, figsize=(30,5))
ax.ravel()
for i, axis in enumerate(ax):
  sns.lineplot(x=df.iloc[:, 1+3*i], y=df.iloc[:, 2+3*i], ax=axis)
  axis.set_title(df.columns[0+3*i])
```